# SYSDATE in c# returns system date rather than server date

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have this simple select query below which fetches records which is one day old from current server `date`

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE_SENT <= SYSDATE - 1";
```

My Oracle server and application are hosted in different servers and timezone is different. The above query fetches records when executed in `Oracle SQL Developer IDE` but it does not fetch any record when it is used in application as below:

```
strQuery="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE_SENT <= SYSDATE - :CHECK_CRITERIA";
OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, objConnection);
objCommand.Parameters.Add("CHECK_CRITERIA", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = decCheckCriteria;
OracleDataReader objDRVendorRecords = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (objDRVendorRecords.HasRows)
{
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

*`CHECK_CRITERIA` will be 1 always.*

When debugged we identified that **`Sysdate`** was giving us the **system date** instead of **server date**.

> My question here is why `sysdate` does not return *database server date*
>   and instead why it returns *current system date*?

Comment: How do you populate the DATE_SENT field? Are you using trigger or manual populate?

Comment: Date_Sent field will be updated using similar update queries. But I don't think this will matter here as the scenario is totally different.

Comment: Just to confirm, in your question, by "current system date" do you mean "application server date"?

Comment: As the SYSDATE will be evaluated by the oracle database server based on the local date, there is no way that the value is Application Server's date. Can you give the real dates you got during debugging for Sysdate , the date of the application server and database servers?

Comment: Just want to confirm that the date format is not overlooked.

Comment: @Martin.. This is `sysdate` I get when I run it in application - `1/20/2016 12:48:36 AM` which is indeed application server date and this is `sysdate` I get when I run it in _Oracle Sql Developer_ `01/20/2016 06:48:35 AM`

Comment: could u pls create a test method in your c# project to execute "select sysdate from dual" and see what is the value you are getting?

Comment: @Martin.. That's how I have given you the above dates.. :) I am aware that `SYSDATE` should give us Oracle server date but am surprised with this behavior..

Comment: Ah! This is strange!! Is there any way you can set up a profiler in your database server to capture this request and see the request is no way altered?

Comment: What do you get by SQL Plus (instead of SQL Developer) for `select sysdate from dual;`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry to say this but this is the only IDE I can test the query here..

Comment: They try `EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));`